# Catkin_make problem with xacro when installing gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros-groovy, ubuntu, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I encountered a problem of xacro when I am trying to install gazebo. which is

CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package xacro.

Set xacro_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
xacro.  The file will have one of the following names:

```
xacroConfig.cmake
xacro-config.cmake
```

I tried to install xacro via ros wiki using  "git clone -b". And it was successfully installed. However the problem still exists. And I have no idea what to do now.
If I try to reinstall the xacro, it will show :
fatal: destination path 'xacro' already exists and is not an empty directory.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77706/catkin_make-problem-with-xacro-when-installing-gazebo/) by [Alex Y.](https://answers.ros.org/users/6571/alex-y./) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Groovy Xacro hasn't been catkinized yet. So a catkinized package can't depend on it. You could try downloading and compile the catkinized source version (branch: hydro-devel) from GitHub: https://github.com/ros/xacro/tree/hydro-devel

Btw, for using Gazebo I recommend you switch to Hydro.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1